# I am trying to separate values in a set with a string

Tags: python, set

I am attempting to insert the string '**" in between values in a set. As well as eliminating the {} in the print of my set.

Thank you in advance for all help/advice.

My output is supposed to look like:

```
    SAMPLE OUTPUT
12**16**17**18**20**21**22**23**24**28**
Set has 7 even numbers and 3 odd numbers
```

My current code is:

```
import random
def main():
random_set = set([])
while len(random_set) < 10:
    random_set.add(random.randrange(10, 31))
print(random_set)
oddcount = 0
for x in random_set:
    if x%2 ==1:
        oddcount += 1
evencount = len(random_set) - oddcount
print('Set has', evencount, 'even numbers and', oddcount,'odd numbers'),
main()
```

And my current output is:

```
{10, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 25, 28, 29, 30}
Set has 7 even numbers and 3 odd numbers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method in order to create a string of an iterable of strings with specified separator between items:

```
In [58]: s = {10, 12, 14, 15, 18, 20, 25, 28, 29, 30}

In [59]: '**'.join(map(str, s))
Out[59]: '10**12**14**15**18**20**25**28**29**30'
```

Note, that `str.join` accepts an iterable of strings, so you have to convert each number to string using `map(str, s)`.

In order to add `**` at the end of the string, you could just use `+` as string concatenation operator:

```
In [60]: '**'.join(map(str, s)) + '**'
Out[60]: '10**12**14**15**18**20**25**28**29**30**'
```

You should also note, that the order of `set` elements is **not specified**. In order to print the elements in the ascending order, you should manually sort them:

```
In [61]: '**'.join(map(str, sorted(s))) + '**'
Out[61]: '10**12**14**15**18**20**25**28**29**30**'
```

Comment: Also 'manually' add a '**' after the last number to have it exactly like the sample output.

Answer (score 1):

What I get is that you're trying to print a delimited sequence. You can use the str join method and the map function to solve this.

```
>>> print("**".join(map(str, random_set)) + "**")
12**16**17**18**20**21**22**23**24**28**
```

Map is converting each element inside of your set to a string equivalent value. The join method returns a string where the elements of a sequence have been joined together with some str separator.

You can use `+` to add the final `**` to the end of your string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for loop that iterates through random_set and then appends all of the items into a list, then print the list joined with `'**'`:

```
list = []
for i in random_set:
    list.append(str(i))
print('**'.join(list)
```

This would print it in the format you want.